# Mobile workaround: how do I append "m" to the URL for redirecting mobiles?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, redirect, mobile

I already have a mobile detecting plugin for WordPress, so now all I need is a script to send the user to the mobile version of the site.

I think the simplest way is to have every desktop page recreated on the mobile subdomain and then simply appending "m" to the start of the URL, so that for example mobile users visiting site.com/page/ get redirected to m.site.com/page/

Here comes my question: how could I achieve that? We've established the user is on a mobile. Now I need to:

a) Edit the current URL by adding m. to the start.
b) Send the user to that new URL.

Thanks!

Comment: where do you want to do this? in PHP/JS?

Comment: PHP really only if possible. I already have the script for detecting the mobile, I just need the PHP for appending m to the current URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this with PHP :

```
header('location: http://m.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Note that you'll have to output nothing before to call this function otherwise you'll have the "Headers already sent" error.

Comment: I need code that redirects the person to the current URL with m appended. I don't want to go on every single page on my website and manually have to write the redirect code to the specific URL...

Comment: You have to try by yourself, we are not here to do ALL your job. I gave you a basic solution, your call to make it better to suit your needs. I edited my answer though.

Comment: Thanks Loic. I apologise, I didn't mean to be rude, I'm just not very adept with any kind of programming. This new edit looks good, I will try it out later. Many thanks.